# Why does my iOS app crash with JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to acces my JSON in Objective-C from a higher scope. But it keeps crashing and I have no idea why.

The following code works:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONOnkectWithData: responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* nameAndPlace = [[json objectForKey:@"objects"] objectForKey:@"havens"];
    //NSArray* productArray = [[json objectForKey:@"objects"] objectForKey:@"products"];

    NSLog(@"FROM ---> %@", nameAndPlace);

    for (NSDictionary *mapPointLoop in nameAndPlace) {
        NSString * name = [mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * longitudeGet = [mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSString * latitudeGet = [mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"latitude"];

        myAnnotation *annotation1 = [[myAnnotation alloc] init];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
        coordinate1.longitude = longitude;
        coordinate1.latitude = latitude;
        annotation1.coordinate = coordinate1;

        annotation1.title = name;

        [mainMap addAnnotation:annotation1];

        //NSLog(@"FROM ---> %@", mapPointLoop);
    }
}
```

But when I use this it crashes:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* nameAndPlace = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];
    //NSArray* productArray = [[json objectForKey:@"objects"] objectForKey:@"products"];

    NSLog(@"FROM -> %@", nameAndP1ace);

    for (NSDictionary *mapPointLoop in nameAndPlace) {
        NSString * name = [[mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"havens"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSNumber * longitudeGet = [mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSNumber * latitudeGet = [mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"latitude"];

        float latitude = [latitudeGet floatvalue];
        float longitude = [longitudeGet floatvalue];

        myAnnotation *annotation1 = [[myAnnotation alloc] init];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
        coordinate1.longitude = longitude;
        coordinate1.latitude = latitude;
        annotation1.coordinate = coordinate1

        annotation1.title = name;

        [mainMap addAnnotation:annotation1];

        //NSLog(@"FROM -> %@", mapPointLoop):
    }
}
```

It crashes with the error...

> 2014-05-20 17:49:57.709 labelAPortTest[5556:60b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1172426b0'

Comment: It's better to post actual code than to post a picture of your code. Text is easier to read, and it can easily be copied into an answer with corrections.

Comment: Any error message containing the word "unrecognised selector"? Show it. Show us a copy of the actual JSON. NSLog of the json variable is enough.

Comment: The two blocks of code are different ... I suspect it's the war you get nameAndPLace that's causing the issue. What's the crash message ?

Comment: It does give me an error that says unrecognized selector gnasher, i'll update my post with the code and JSON

Comment: 2014-05-20 17:49:57.709 labelAPortTest[5556:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1172426b0'

Comment: I've transcribed the screenshots. If someone could sanity check them it'd be appreciated...

Comment: @Edd ha! Nice to see you here :D Good work on the transcription :D

Comment: @NanDamhuis you should select the right answer so the topic is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crash because when you take the name:

```
NSString *name = [[mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"havnes"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

this:

```
[mapPointLoop objectForKey:@"havens"]
```

is an `NSArray` and not an `NSDictionary` with the key `name`.

In fact in your first code you take the `objectForKey:@"objects"] objectForKey:@"havens]"`
so you have this situation:

`NSDictionary` ~> ***objects*** ~> `NSDictionary` ~> ***havens*** ~> `NSArray` (of `NSDictionary`)

then you go to through a for cycle getting 1 to 1 the `NSDictionary` in the `NSArray`.

Second case (that crash):

`NSDictionary` ~> ***objects*** ~> `NSDictionary`

but your are putting that in an `NSArray` going again with the for cycle..on an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

> But it keeps crashing and I have no idea why.

The reason is right here:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1172426b0'
```

You have an uncaught exception. Furthermore, you have some information about what that exception is, namely that you're sending the `objectForKey:` message to an object that doesn't implement it.

The first thing you should do is to set a breakpoint for all exceptions:

[image: setting an exception breakpoint]

That'll cause the debugger to stop as soon as the exception is thrown instead of waiting until the app exits, which will give you a lot more context. You should be able to see which object is getting the unknown message. If that doesn't make the problem completely clear, set a breakpoint a line or two before the exception happens and step through the code a line at a time until you find the problem.